# Animation causing out of memory exception

Tags: java, android, animation, out-of-memory

My application provides an `outofmemory` exception when an animation starts to play. What can I do?
The images in animation combined have a size of 512kb, that's 10 images.

My activity class is `button_anime`.

```
 public class Button_Anime extends Activity{

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 500;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_about);
    ImageView loading =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iVArcRail_2);
    loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.about_button_anime);
    AnimationDrawable load =(AnimationDrawable)loading.getBackground();
    load.start();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               
        @Override
        public void run() {
               Intent i = new Intent(Button_Anime.this, Home.class); 
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
  }
 }
```

My `activity_splash_about.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/withoutlogo" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logoline" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iVArcRail_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the animation file. `about_button_anime`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:oneshot="false" >
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab1"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab2"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab3"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab4"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab5"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab6"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab7"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab8"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab9"
      android:duration="50"/>
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/ab10"
      android:duration="50"/>
  
  </animation-list>
```

And this is my log cat.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.quinoid.thomasinternational, PID: 1514
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
 at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
 at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15303)
 at com.quinoid.thomasinternational.Button_Anime.onCreate(Button_Anime.java:19)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I get this animation running?

I have already provided `largeHeap="true"`.

Comment: add `android:largeHeap="true"` AndroidManifeast. it helps you

Answer (score 4):

This will work like charm,

Make sure you put your images in the asset folder.

```
public class AnimationActivily extends Activity {

private Bitmap log_imgs[];
private Bitmap tempBitmap;
private Handler uiHandler;
private ImageView logo_view;
int img_cnt = 1;
protected int _splashTime = 91;
Thread splashTread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation_activily);
    logo_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_view);
    log_imgs = new Bitmap[91];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 90; i++) {
        get_Images_Assest(i, "logo_pngs");
    }
    logo_view.setImageBitmap(log_imgs[70]);
    uiHandler = new Handler();
    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (img_cnt < _splashTime) {
                    sleep(30);
                    if (img_cnt <= 90)
                        update_view(img_cnt);
                    img_cnt++;

                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {

                Intent i = new Intent(AnimationActivily.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(i);
                AnimationActivily.this.finish();
                // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,
                // R.anim.slide_out);
                // *** Put this in another
                // Activity***//overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,
                // R.anim.slide_out);
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();

}

public Bitmap tempImg;

private void get_Images_Assest(int cnt, String folder_name) {
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open(
                folder_name + "/" + "logo" + cnt + ".png");
        if (tempImg != null) {
            tempImg = null;
        }
        tempImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        // tempBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempImg,
        // tempImg.getWidth() * 2, tempImg.getHeight() * 2, true);
        log_imgs[cnt] = tempImg;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void update_view(final int cnt) {
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                logo_view.setImageBitmap(log_imgs[cnt]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void onBackPressed() {
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 90; i++) {
        log_imgs[i].recycle();
    }
    log_imgs = null;
    splashTread = null;
}
}
```

Comment: what is the "logo_pngs" in get_Images_Assest(i, "logo_pngs");

Comment: also what is log_imgs in logo_view.setImageBitmap(log_imgs[70]);

Comment: hey sorry for late reply, logo_pngs is the folder name, and log_imgs if the array of the bitmap created from assets.

Comment: -- You can create a folder in assets folder give any name to it
-- Replace the name with the new name
-- Now put ur images in the folder with same name just appen _0 .. _10 ... _14 according to ur sequence

Comment: You can give any name to the file, eg ur file name are 

img_0.png, img_1.png, img_3.png and img_4.png

Then change:

InputStream is = getAssets().open(
                folder_name + "/" + "img" + cnt + ".png");

for loop would be 

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        get_Images_Assest(i, "logo_pngs");
    }

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I created a class to avoid from OutOfMemoryError. Android loads all the drawables at once, so animation with many frames causes this error.

## FasterAnimationsContainer

FasterAnimationsContainer will help you to avoid from OutOfMemoryError. This class loads & sets and releases an image on background thread.

here's [link](https://github.com/tigerjj/FasterAnimationsContainer)

### Easy to implement

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

FasterAnimationsContainer mFasterAnimationsContainer;
private static final int[] IMAGE_RESOURCES = { R.drawable.anim_1,
        R.drawable.anim_2, R.drawable.anim_3, R.drawable.anim_4,
        R.drawable.anim_5, R.drawable.anim_6, R.drawable.anim_7,
        R.drawable.anim_8 };

private static final int ANIMATION_INTERVAL = 500;// 200ms

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    mFasterAnimationsContainer = FasterAnimationsContainer
            .getInstance(imageView);
    mFasterAnimationsContainer.addAllFrames(IMAGE_RESOURCES,
            ANIMATION_INTERVAL);
    mFasterAnimationsContainer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mFasterAnimationsContainer.stop();
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried with your class but when i return back to the screen on which frame animation is implemented, it is showing nothing. It shows blank Image View.

Comment: it is running repeatedly , how to make it run only one time

Comment: This library doesn't work! besides accesses UI thread from a worker thread!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my background animation on devices with low memory.
The way I managed to fix it was by instantiating the animation programmatically instead of through the xml animation-list. I no longer run into out of memory issues with this view.

```
    AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();
    animationDrawable.setOneShot(false); // True = only once, False = continuous

    int[] resources = {R.drawable.ticket_background_animation_1, R.drawable.ticket_background_animation_2, R.drawable.ticket_background_animation_3};

    int duration = 30;

    for (int resource : resources) {
        animationDrawable.addFrame(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resource), duration);
    }

    relativeLayout.setBackground(animationDrawable);
    animationDrawable.start();
```

It's of course also very important to remember to stop the animation again in **onDestroy()**!

```
    ((AnimationDrawable) relativeLayout.getBackground()).stop();
    // Sets background to null to make sure the animation is garbage collected
    relativeLayout.setBackground(null);
```